# I'm trying to select Payment option in select list in firefox browser but it is not selecting

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Here im trying to select Payment option in select list and working on Firefox browser.

```
 <select id="IDITForm@claimReserveReasonVO@id" class="SelectInput" onclick="closeAfterUnload = false" onblur="releaseCurrentFocusField()" helptextinfo="" onfocus="onFocusFieldHandler(this)" onchange="closeAfterUnload = false" onkeypress="onComboKeyPress(this)" style="width: 328px; visibility: visible;" name="IDITForm@claimReserveReasonVO@id" tabindex="217" origvalue="-1" value="-1">
    <option value="-1">Select</option>
    <option value="11">Damage Closed</option>
    <option value="10">Ex- gratia</option>
    <option value="4">Invoice</option>
    <option value="6">Medical information</option>
    <option value="1">Open new damage</option>
    <option value="7">Payment</option>
    <option value="3">Proposal</option>
    <option value="5">Report assessor</option>
    <option value="12">Storno payment</option>
    </select>
```

I have tried using the following code but nothing succeeds

```
b.select_list(:id, 'IDITForm@claimReserveReasonVO@id').select "Payment"
b.select_list(:id, 'IDITForm@claimReserveReasonVO@id').option(:text,'Payment').select
b.select_list(:id, 'IDITForm@claimReserveReasonVO@id').option(:value,'7').select
```

but I have written the below code to print the options, it works fine, that is, It's printing all the options.

```
b.select_list(:id, 'IDITForm@claimReserveReasonVO@id').options.each do |option|
  puts option.text
end
```

Note : It works perfectly in Chrome but not in Firefox.

Comment: Are you trying to select this option in a test?

Comment: Cannot repro using `watir 6.1.0` + `FF 51.0.1` + `geckodriver 14` on Win7.    Are you saying it silently fails (i.e. no error but the option is not selected)?

Comment: @orde I and Naresh work together, Yes, option is not selected, but it doesn't fail either, it move on to the next line. But in chrome it selects the option fine.

Comment: Sorry, but it's works for me using the versions listed above.  If you're not using the latest bits, you might want to try updating.  YMMV.

Comment: @orde If I take out this code separately and create the html page separately, it works for me as well, but it's not working for me in my application. But the same code works when I work with Chrome.

Comment: Bummer.  Sounds like there's something application-specific that you're going to need to chase down.

Comment: @orde It runs in  'legacy Firefox' and it runs in Chrome but it's not running only when we use 'Geckodriver'.

Comment: Understood.  But--if you "take out this code separately and create the html page separately, it works", then it sounds "like there's something application-specific that you're going to need to chase down".  And "legacy firefox" is version 47, which is 6+ months old at this point with ever-diminishing market share.